# calculating the mean values of duplicate entries in a dataframe and placing them in the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose we have a dataframe like this:

```
    reviewerId  productId   overall
0   A1REUF3A1YCPHM  0001713353  5.0
1   AVP0HXC9FG790   0001713353  5.0
2   A324TTUBKTN73A  0001713353  2.0
3   A2RE7WG349NV5D  0001713353  4.0
...
16  A1IG9N5URR82EB  0001061240  5.0
17  A2CVLIZ9ELU88   0001061240  1.0
18  A2LGACKSC0MALY  0001061240  5.0
19  A6EQG0P75KHJ    0001061240  3.0
```

now we will sort them and find the average of them with this code:

```
df_final = df.groupby(['productId'], as_index=False)['overall'].mean()
```

now I want to have a column named 'average' and place the average in front of all rows of the 'df' not 'df_final' like this:

```
    reviewerId  productId   overall  average
0   A1REUF3A1YCPHM  0001713353  5.0  4.75
1   AVP0HXC9FG790   0001713353  5.0  4.75
2   A324TTUBKTN73A  0001713353  2.0  4.75
3   A2RE7WG349NV5D  0001713353  4.0  4.75
...
16  A1IG9N5URR82EB  0001061240  5.0  4.5
17  A2CVLIZ9ELU88   0001061240  1.0  4.5
18  A2LGACKSC0MALY  0001061240  5.0  4.5
19  A6EQG0P75KHJ    0001061240  3.0  4.5
```

consider the fact that we have over 20 million rows and I want the optimized way.

Comment: sounds like you should probably do this using a window function in SQL given the size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform`:

```
df['average'] = df.groupby('productId', as_index=False)['overall'].transform('mean')
```